# NixOs: use services on non-nixos OS, eventually with only user rights

Tags: systemd, nixos

I would like to know how to run a service described, like in a module on a non-Nix OS. For example let us say I have the file:

```
{config, pkgs, ... }:
{
  systemd.user.services.mytestservice = {
    description = "Mytestservice";
    script = "while true; do echo 'YES'; sleep 1; done";
    wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
 };
}
```

(or eventually without the user: `systemd.services.mytestservice =`)

How can I compile it and run it on non-nixos OS, eventually by non-root users?

Comment: This question need to be made clearer, if you expect a quality response.

Answer (score 2):

Acknowledgment: Thanks a lot to `clever` for all the explanations!

Let us first write the configuration file in `myconfiguration.nix`:

```
{config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  # You can actually remove the user, and still use it
  # as a user if you link it in ~/.config/systemd/user/
  # (do not forget to remove the `user` it in anything.nix
  # as well)
  systemd.user.services.mytestservice = {
   description = "Mytestservice";
   script = "while true; do echo 'YES'; sleep 1; done";
   # Or:
   # serviceConfig = {
   #   ExecStart = "${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash -c \"while true; do echo 'YES'; sleep 1; done\"";
   # };
   wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
 };
}
```

Then, you can de several things:

- compile it
- install it

To compile only, you can do:

```
nix-build '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -I nixos-config=myconfiguration.nix -A 'config.systemd.user.units."mytestservice.service".unit'
```

The idea is that this loads the file `default.nix` in the folder `/your/nixpkgs/copy/nixos/` (to get the path of `nixpkgs`, it checks the variable `NIX_PATH` that contains several "subkeys" like : `NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=/your/nixpkgs/copy/:othervar=thepath`), which is available online [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/default.nix#L1). This file requires also `<nixos-config>`, to we use `-I` to add a nixos-config entry to the `NIX_PATH` environment variable. Then without the `-A`, it will try to build a full nixos, so we just specify that we want only this service unit.

This will produce a file `mytestservice.service` that will look like that:

```
$ cat result/mytestservice.service 
[Unit]
Description=Mytestservice

[Service]
Environment="LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/nix/store/zzhablipzgpv8mvlcvagqjnham6lr944-glibc-locales-2.27/lib/locale/locale-archive"
Environment="PATH=/nix/store/bv1lw6a2kw0mn2y3lxhi43180idx6sp9-coreutils-8.31/bin:/nix/store/s1n4vl1f3in3nacalrc3xam0vyzpsfvs-findutils-4.6.0/bin:/nix/store/7d9bi31h40hky30f5scqx7r6wn311ain-gnugrep-3.3/bin:/nix/store/qg4qbkbca7qapfzpa8p991yjf944fc3w-gnused-4.7/bin:/nix/store/6bvd29jny80ka8df9prr5hrl5yz7d98k-systemd-239.20190219/bin:/nix/store/bv1lw6a2kw0mn2y3lxhi43180idx6sp9-coreutils-8.31/sbin:/nix/store/s1n4vl1f3in3nacalrc3xam0vyzpsfvs-findutils-4.6.0/sbin:/nix/store/7d9bi31h40hky30f5scqx7r6wn311ain-gnugrep-3.3/sbin:/nix/store/qg4qbkbca7qapfzpa8p991yjf944fc3w-gnused-4.7/sbin:/nix/store/6bvd29jny80ka8df9prr5hrl5yz7d98k-systemd-239.20190219/sbin"
Environment="TZDIR=/nix/store/20wmykp8fj2izxdj8lic8ggcfpdid5ka-tzdata-2019a/share/zoneinfo"



ExecStart=/nix/store/1f0wk7l4p7xv257dci8xxqz1k8nai9va-unit-script-mytestservice-start
```

Now, if you want to be able to call it, you need to install it:

```
nix-env -f '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -I nixos-config=myconfiguration.nix -iA 'config.systemd.user.units."mytestservice.service".unit'
```

This will link the `mytestservice.service` into `~/.nix-profile/mytestservice.service`. But systemctl expects it to be in `~/.config/systemd/user/`, so we link it:

```
ln -s ~/.nix-profile/mytestservice.service ~/.config/systemd/user/
```

Then we need to reload the daemon, and we can try playing with it:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user start mytestservice.service
```

Note however that the build/install commands are complicated and long to type, so we can create a file, say `anything.nix`, that will build everything for us:

```
let
  eval = import <nixpkgs/nixos> {
    configuration = ./myconfiguration.nix;
  };
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs>{};
in pkgs.buildEnv {
  name = "things";
  paths = [
    eval.config.systemd.user.units."mytestservice.service".unit
  ];
}
```

Now, you can compile with:

```
nix-build anything.nix
```

and install with

```
nix-env -f anything.nix -i things
```

Note that you may need to remove the first time the file we installed with the other method, by using something like:

```
nix-env --query
nix-env --uninstall unit-mytestservice.service
```

Finally, both codes `systemd.services` and `systemd.services.users` seems to be usable with this method :D